# Android Pattern having problem with $ sign

Tags: android, regex

I am having problem with android regex pattern.

My target is to find **{#}** inside one sentence and replaces them with an array of String.

For example, my raw string will be

> {#} students go to {#}.

My replacement array will be

> ["5","park"]

After replacing, final string should be "5 students go to park." My current snippet work just fine until the replacement array comes up with $ sign such as

> ["$5","$park"]

Here is my current snippet.

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\{#\\})");
 String raw_q = "Pete has {#}. He bought {#}.";
 String[] var = ["$70","6 pens at $5 each"];
 String act_q = "";
 for (int m = 0; m < var.length(); m++) {
    try{
       act_q = raw_q.replaceFirst(pattern.pattern(),var[m]);
    }catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Result is a blank string which I believe try block never get executed. Stack trace shows arrayindexoutofbound exception. I don't really get what it's happening. Any help would be appreciated.

*Note - the length of replacement array is always equal to the number of **{#}** occurrences.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your problem, see the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29). `String.replaceFirst()` use `Matcher.replaceFirst()`, which refers to `Matcher.appendReplacement()`:

> Note that backslashes () and dollar signs ($) in the replacement
>   string may cause the results to be different than if it were being
>   treated as a literal replacement string. Dollar signs may be treated
>   as references to captured subsequences as described above, and
>   backslashes are used to escape literal characters in the replacement
>   string.

That is, you must escape all `$` and `\`.

---

But you have other problem.... You have compile a pattern and NOT use it! `replaceFirst()` always compile the pattern again. Try this for better performance.

```
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(raw_q);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
int i = 0;
while (m.find()) {
     m.appendReplacement(sb, var[i].replaceAll("\\$", "\\\\$"));
     i++;
}
m.appendTail(sb);
act_q = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. This is just what i needed.

Comment: while (m.find()) {
     m.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(var[i]));
     i++;
}

This will do a better job in finding $ and /.

Comment: `$` only needs to be escaped if it is the *last symbol* (disregarding groupers). Otherwise it has no special meaning -- "must escape all" is erring on the side of caution ;-)